# Javascript opens new window despite no call

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript that opens a new window for "PreChecking" a site. The problem is when i click the button, it works fine... but wichever i button i press next makes the method fire again, despite i doesn't call it. Its just the button with id "lnkPrecheck" that should call the method.
Have searched far and wide for a slolution that just opens a new window for the lnkPrecheck button, not the others on the site.
THere must be a way for only 1 of 3 buttons makes the function call, not all of them!

The code:

```
<asp:Button OnClick="lnkPrecheck_Click" OnClientClick="NewWindow();" ID="lnkPrecheck" runat="server" text="Precheck (Opens in a new window)" />

    function NewWindow() {
            document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
}
```

Comment: If the HTML + JS isn't giving the result you expect then post the HTML + JS. If the ASP isn't outputting the HTML + JS you expect, then post those. Don't just post the ASP and JS and hope that people know enough about both technologies to figure out what the ASP will generate and why it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: The other buttons that you press, are they related to that particular form that you've changed the target of?

Comment: why not use `LinkButton` and set its target `_blank`

Comment: I cannot use linkbutton for various reasons, already tried that approach, but it messes up the design. the other buttons are in the same form on the page, yes

Comment: David. i posted the only things that you'd need to solve the problem, sience i tagged it for both technologies i would assume only the folk with appropiate knowledge would post.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var NewWindow = function() {
        document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
        return false; // Prevents ASP.NET-buttons from performing default behavior
    }    
</script>

<asp:Button OnClick="lnkPrecheck_Click" OnClientClick="NewWindow();" ID="lnkPrecheck" runat="server" text="Precheck (Opens in a new window)" />
```

Not sure if setting the `target` of a form to `_blank` will open a new window though.

Comment: That code doesn't work. It doesnt make the button call the function!

Comment: Well, my old code works. Once the button is pressed, all other button clicks will open a new window... Thats the problem, i only want it to open in a new window if the correct button is clicked

Answer (score 2):

If you have any `<input type="button" ... />` or `<button>` tags within a form, you have to make their `onclick` handlers return false (or otherwise cancel any click events). Otherwise their default behavior is to submit the form, even though they're not explict "submit" buttons.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean.. could you use my code and give me an example? Not really a pro at javascript ^^

Comment: Take a blank form like this: `<form><button>Click me</button></form>`. CLick the button, it'll submit the form, even though it's not a submit button at all. To stop that, you have to do `<button onclick="return false">Click me</button>`

Comment: If i do that and call Return false on the buttons i dont want to open a new window, they wont do what theyre supposed to either.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real "solution" to your problem.

Once you set the form target, it stick for good. It's not reverting back to the original target.

One way around is store the original target as custom attribute then "reset" the target when clicking other buttons.

Code for that would be:

```
function NewWindow() {
   var oForm = document.forms[0];
   var curTarget = oForm.target;
   if (curTarget != "_blank")
      oForm.setAttribute("org_target", curTarget);
   oForm.target = "_blank";
}

function ResetTarget() {
   var oForm = document.forms[0];
   oForm.target = oForm.getAttribute("org_target");
}
```

Then in all other buttons call the `ResetTarget` function first.

Comment: SO there is no way to make so only 1 button uses a script and opens a new window? That sounds very strange! The page has 3 buttons, cant i just make a condition.. if not the right condition the page wont open in a new window.

Comment: @Jimmy the code you posted does not open new window, it changes form target. To open new window use `window.open("mynewpage.html", "_blank");` instead of your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Once try this...

It's working for me..

Use this for the asp.net control where you want to open in a new tab.

```
 OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='_new'; setTimeout(function(){window.document.forms[0].target='';}, 500);"
```